# SendMail method missing in SharePoint Utility Class

Tags: csom, send-email

What happen to **SendMail** method in SharePoint **Utility** Class?  Why is it missing for me?

[image]

As per the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee543811%28v%3Doffice.15%29) it does exists.  But why I don't see it? I am using C# CSOM.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` you are using?

Comment: This was a version mismatch issue.  I removed old library and added it again.